Global Function access in Postman
My question is can we make a function in postman and declare it global that we can access throughout the workspace? is it possible if yes how we can do this?

With V11 of Postman, you can use the Package Library to create scripts at the team level and call these into a Collection at the different script levels.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/tests-and-scripts/write-scripts/package-library/

I create a few helper utils and added them to a gist:
https://gist.github.com/DannyDainton/dd098b730a643f2d2be9b544953ccb5b

Define a global variable in your pre-request script (either at the request, folder or collection level according to your needs).  No const, var or let.
You will need to pass pm as an argument if you want to utilize those methods.
For example...
utils = {
    statusCode: function (pm, code) {
        pm.test(`Status code is ${code}`, () => {
            pm.response.to.have.status(code);
        })
        return 'hello';
    },
    response: function (pm) {
        console.log(pm.response.json());
        return 'hello';
    }
};

To call those functions
utils.response(pm);
utils.statusCode(pm, 200);

